# themeing and reordering items on the drupal commerce checkout review pane

Tags: drupal, hook, checkout, review, commerce

How can I possibly theme/reorder items of a pane on the checkout review page?
I have a pane called custom_info:

**custom info**

- Name
- Phone
- Address
- Date

Let's say I want the "Date" to be first, I want to add some text or put a few items on the same line. how do I go about doing that in a custom module?

Thanks!

Comment: I have not used commerce for a while, but isn't it a form? So you could do a [form alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)